# Groups with many vanishing elements

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, characters

It is well-known that every non-linear character $\chi$ of a finite group $G$ vanishes on some elements of $G\setminus Z(\chi)$. The question is

What can be said about a finite group $G$ for which $\chi(x)=0$ for all irreducible character $\chi$ and elements $x\in G\setminus Z(\chi)$?

Here, $Z(\chi)=\{g\in G:|\chi(g)|=\chi(1)\}$. So, $Z(\chi)/\ker\chi=Z(G/\ker\chi)$.

Comment: As an example, any split metacyclic $p$-group of odd order has the mentioned property. Also, the same holds for split metacyclic $2$-groups with few exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These appear to be the groups that I was asking about in [this older MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56380/characters-on-a-finite-group-with-extremal-behaviour) -- see in particular the answers by Isaacs and Ladisch.